# Making so a user fails thier rob attempt discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Okay so I wrote a small code for the user who fails their rob attempt. I just have no idea where to put it. The way it works is if someone says `;rob` it returns a message `TestUser, you were caught and paid 500 coins to the user you were robbing from!` when that message displays the author would loose 500 coins and the target would gain 500 coins.

The code of the current rob command is

```js
run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const cooldown = cooldowns.get(message.author.id);
    if (cooldown) {
        const remaining = humanizeDuration(cooldown - Date.now(),{ units: ['m', 's'],round: true });
        let cEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTitle("Slow down, cmon!")
        .setDescription(`You will be able to work in \`${remaining}\` just you wait!\n\nWhile you wait why not follow our [Twitter](https://twitter.com/switchoffical)`)

        return message.channel.send(cEmbed)
        .catch(console.error);
    } else {
        let member = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]);
        let user = message.mentions.members.first()
        if (!user) return message.channel.send('Sorry, you forgot to mention somebody.')
        let targetuser = await db.fetch(`money_${user.id}`) // fetch mentioned users balance
        let author = await db.fetch(`money_${message.author.id}`) // fetch authors balance
        let uBalance = balance[member.id].balance;
        let TuBalance = balance[user.id].balance;
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1; // random number 200-1, you can change 200 to whatever you'd like
        let curBal = balance[message.author.id].balance 
        balance[message.author.id].balance = curBal + random;
        let crurBal = balance[message.author.id].balance 
        balance[user.id].balance = crurBal - random;

        if (uBalance < 500) { // if the authors balance is less than 250, return this.
            return message.channel.send(':x: You need at least 500$ to rob somebody.')
        }

        if (TuBalance < 0) { // if mentioned user has 0 or less, it will return this.
            return message.channel.send(`:x: ${user.user.username} does not have anything to rob.`)
        }


        message.channel.send(`${message.author} you robbed ${user} and got away with ${random}!`)

        cooldowns.set(message.author.id, Date.now() + 900000);
        setTimeout(() => cooldowns.delete(message.author.id), 900000);

        db.subtract(`money_${user.id}`, random)
        db.add(`money_${message.author.id}`, random)
    } 
}
```

I have set up the failchance and the message the only thing left is where do I put it in the current code and how would I make it subtract 500 coins from the author and give 500 coins to the target. I would also like it to that the chances of them having a successful robbery is very low. Here is the fail code

```js
var failChance = Math.floor((Math.random()500)*4);
if(failChance === 0){
     message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}** you were caught so you paied 500 coins to the user you were robbing from.`);
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I suggest you to handle your success/fail scenario :

```js
...

else {

    ...

    if (TuBalance < 0) { // if mentioned user has 0 or less, it will return this.
        return message.channel.send(`:x: ${user.user.username} does not have anything to rob.`)
    }

    let testChance = Math.random() * 100;

    // 5 here is percentage of success.
    if ((testChance -= 5) < 0) {
        // Success!
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} you robbed ${user} and got away with ${random}!`);
        db.subtract(`money_${user.id}`, random);
        db.add(`money_${message.author.id}`, random);
    } else {
        // Fail :(
        message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}** you were caught so you paied 500 coins to the user you were robbing from.`);
        db.add(`money_${user.id}`, random);
        db.subtract(`money_${message.author.id}`, random);
    }

    cooldowns.set(message.author.id, Date.now() + 900000);
    setTimeout(() => cooldowns.delete(message.author.id), 900000);
}
```

Here is a little utility function for you :

```js
/**
 * Test chance out of 100.
 * @param {Number} succesPercentage Percentage of chance to succes.
 * @returns {Boolean} Whenever the test is a succes or not. 
 */
function testChance(successPercentage) {
    let random = Math.random() * 100;
    return ((random -= successPercentage) < 0);
}
```

Usage :

```js
if (testChance(5)) {
    // Success scenario
} else {
    // Fail scenario
}
```